# How to obtain one by one in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am trying to obtain, one by one, the elements in IndexedDB. My target is:

1. Obtain the first `element[key].verbo` and `adjetivo` and `sustativo` and print in html, to see in the web.
2. Wait to the user insert a one sentence in what includes these words and click check.
3. Obtain the second `element[key].verbo` and `adjetivo` and `sustativo` and print in html, to see in the web.
4. The same as 2.

And continue in the same way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>IndexedDB: Local Database with HTML5</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
            var dataBase = null;
            var pulsador = false;
            function startDB() {

                dataBase = indexedDB.open('db', 1);

                dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
                    var active = dataBase.result;

                    var object = active.createObjectStore("people", {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});
                    object.createIndex('by_adjetivo', 'adjetivo', {unique: false});
                    object.createIndex('by_verbo', 'verbo', {unique: true});
                };

                dataBase.onsuccess = function (e) {
                    alert('Base de datos cargada');
                    loadAll();
                };
                dataBase.onerror = function (e) {
                    alert('Error al cargar Base de datos');
                };
            }

            function add() {

                var active = dataBase.result;
                var data = active.transaction(["people"], "readwrite");
                var object = data.objectStore("people");

                var request = object.put({
                    verbo: document.querySelector("#verbo").value,
                    adjetivo: document.querySelector("#adjetivo").value,
                    sustantivo: document.querySelector("#sustantivo").value
                });

                request.onerror = function (e) {
                    alert(request.error.adjetivo + '\n\n' + request.error.message);
                };

                data.oncomplete = function (e) {
                    document.querySelector('#verbo').value = '';
                    document.querySelector('#adjetivo').value = '';
                    document.querySelector('#sustantivo').value = '';
                    alert('Object successfully added');
                    loadAll();
                };
            }

            function loadAll() {

                var active = dataBase.result;
                var data = active.transaction(["people"], "readonly");
                var object = data.objectStore("people");

                var elements = [];

                object.openCursor().onsuccess = function (e) {

                    var result = e.target.result;

                    if (result === null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    elements.push(result.value);
                    result.continue();

                };

                data.oncomplete = function () {
                    var outerHTML = '';
                    for (var key in elements) {
                        v=elements[key].verbo;

                        outerHTML+='\n\ <tr>\n\<td>' 
                             +"\t"+"Verbo: \t"+ elements[key].verbo + '</td>\n\<td>' 
                             +"\t"+"Adjetivo: \t"+ elements[key].adjetivo + '</td>\n\ <td>'
                             +"\t"+"Sustantivo: \t"+ elements[key].sustantivo 
                             + '</td>\n\ </tr>';
                        document.querySelector("#elementsList").innerHTML = outerHTML; // I want print one verbo,adjetivo and sustantivo

                        gradeTest(elements[key].verbo,elements[key].adjetivo,elements[key].sustantivo); //Before, i want 

                    }

                    elements = [];

                };

            }


            function gradeTest(p1,p2,p3) {
                var a1 = document.getElementById('q1').value.toLowerCase();
                if(a1.includes(p1) )
                    if (a1.includes(p2)) 
                        if (a1.includes(p3)) {
                            alert('They are equal');//and we can continue to two elements[key].
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startDB();">
        <input type="text" id="verbo" placeholder="Enter verbo" />
        <input type="text" id="adjetivo" placeholder="Enter adjetivo" />
        <input type="text" id="sustantivo" placeholder="Enter sustantivo" />
        <button type="button" onclick="add();">Save</button>
        <hr>
        <div id="elements">
            <table>
                <caption>g</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Verbo</th>
                        <th>Adjetivo</th>
                        <th>Sustantivo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="elementsList">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">Not elements to show</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tr>
                <td>introduce one verb,adjetive and sustantive</td>
                <td><input name="q1" type="text" id="q1" size="30" maxlength="30"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input name="submit" type="button" onClick="gradeTest()" value="check"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: It looks like the native language used here is Spanish. Please do note there is a site, [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/), which might help you in your presumptive native language. I'm sure we can help in English too, but just thought I'd advertise the language-specific site just in case :).

Comment: Also, if you want to keep this here, please let us know what is wrong with the code you already have written. For instance, any errors you may be seeing in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an array of the items before hand and using a global variable to track the position in the items array. For example:

```
// Declare a global variable to hold the items
var items = [];

// Open a connection and query for items
function fillItems() {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open('mydb, 1);
  openRequest.onsuccess = onOpenConnection;
}

// Query the store for all items
function onOpenConnection(openRequestEvent) {
  if(openRequestEvent.type !== 'success' ) {
    console.log('connection error');
    return;
  }

  var connection = openRequestEvent.target.result;
  var transaction = connection.transaction('mystorename');
  var store = transaction.objectStore('mystorename');
  var request = store.openCursor();
  request.onsuccess = addNextItemFromDatabase;
}

// Add the item at the cursor's current position to the items array,
// and then request the cursor to advance by 1
function addNextItemFromDatabase(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if(cursor) {
    items.push(cursor.value);
    cursor.continue();
  }
}

// When page is loaded, fill the items array
fillItems();
// Global variable that keeps track of index into items array
var currentItemPosition = -1;
// Get the button the user clicks
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
// Attach a click listener function that is called whenever the 
// button is clicked
button.onclick = function(event) {
  // Increment the current position by 1 each time the button 
  // is clicked
  currentItemPosition = currentItemPosition + 1;

  // Check if in bounds
  if(currentItemPosition >= items.length) {
    console.log('out of bounds');
    return;
  }

  // Get the item at the current position
  var currentItem = items[currentItemPosition];
  console.log(currentItem.verbo);
  console.log(currentItem.adjectivo);
  // etc..
};
```